# "Proposed changes" page doesn't remember markdown diff render setting

Tags: bug, documentation, markdown, documentation-proposals, diff

The title says it all, really.

When opening a proposed change, the markdown diff view never seems to remember my "side-by-side" choice.

For example, take [this proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/49488).
Chose a different diff rendering option, then refresh the page.

For me, It resets to "Inline" every single time.

Comment: Has this worked in the past or is it a new feature request?

Comment: This works on SO / meta. The setting is remembered everywhere but Doc.

Comment: Didn't realize that. Seems like it would be useful though for sure

Comment: Frankly, it not working is a "pita". The inline option is simply useless, and I really don't care for that option being selected automatically.

Comment: That makes sense too. I'd agree with that.